# HTML5 and php email form is not sending details

Tags: php, html

I am hoping someone can help me out here.  I have created a webpage with a contact form in HTML5 and php.  When I press the submit button, an email gets sent to where it is supposed to but all the fields are blank.

I know I have missed something simple, but I just can't see it.

Here is the HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php">
<label form="HTML Form">Full Name:</label>
<input maxlength="45" size="35" placeholder="Full Name" required name="name" id="name" type="text">
<label form="HTML Form">Phone Number:</label>
<input maxlength="45" size="35" placeholder="Phone" required name="phone" id="phone" type="text">
<label form="HTML Form">Email Address:</label>
<input maxlength="75" size="35" placeholder="Email Address" required name="email" id="email" type="email">
<label form="HTML Form">Comment:</label>
<textarea maxlength="300" placeholder="Comment"
    wrap="soft"
    rows="10"
    cols="40"
    name="comment" id="comment"
    required></textarea>
<input formmethod="post" value="Send" formaction="submit.php" type="submit">
<br>
</form>
```

and here is the php

```
<?php

/* checking if data was sent */
if(isset($_POST))
{
      foreach($_POST as $key => $field)
        {
            if(trim($field==""))
              echo "this field is required, your input is blank:   <b>$key</b>     <br>";
            $key=$field; //putting the response into variables
        }

    /* starting the email message */
    $to = "email@mywebsite.com"; // your email address
    $subject = "Contact form submission";
    $message = "Full Name: $name <br> Phone: $phone <br>";
    $message .= "Email Address: $email <br> Comment: <br> $comment";
    $headers = "From:" . $from."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
        echo "Email was sent";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the assignment of `$_POST` variables:

```
  foreach($_POST as $key => $field)
    {
        if(trim($field==""))
          echo "this field is required, your input is blank:   <b>$key</b>     <br>";
        $$key=$field; //putting the response into variables  # <------
    }
```

You have to use the syntax `$$key` to create a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Your assignment set the `$key` variable to last value of `$_POST` array.

**Also please note:** where is defined `$from` variable?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't grabbing the variable from the POST array.
e.g.
$phone = $_POST['phone'] etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert the `$_POST` key names into variables then you need to do this: `$$key = $field;` instead of `$key = $field;`. These are [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).